# pytest cannot find pip module

Tags: python, pytest

I have the project structure that looks like this

```
\project
    \app.py
    \tests
        \__init__.py
        \test_startup.py
```

`app.py` looks like this

```
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from starlette.responses import UJSONResponse
from starlette.routing import Route


async def homepage(request):
    return UJSONResponse({'hello': 'world'})


app = Starlette(debug=True, routes=[
    Route('/', homepage)
])
```

`test_startup.py` looks like this

```
from starlette.testclient import TestClient

from ..app import app


def test_app():
    client = TestClient(app)
    response = client.get('/')
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

`__init__.py` is an empty file.

When I try to run `pytest -v` from my project directory it fails with the error

```
tests/test_startup.py:1: in <module>
    from starlette.testclient import TestClient
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'starlette'
```

I am able to run the application. Also I was trying to put `conftest.py` into both - `tests` and `project` folders and it did not help.

What is the problem?

Comment: Did you install starlette in the virtual environment or to your main python interpreter?

Comment: @KrishnanShankar yes, I have installed it all and able to run it separately - like just executing `app.py` file. but in tests it fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this import:

```
from ..app import app
```

to this:

```
from app import app
```

I ran your code exactly as posted, and got a `E   ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`. Once the import was changed, `pytest -v` was successful:

```
darkstar:~/tmp/project $ cat app.py
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from starlette.responses import UJSONResponse
from starlette.routing import Route


async def homepage(request):
    return UJSONResponse({'hello': 'world'})


app = Starlette(debug=True, routes=[
    Route('/', homepage)
])
darkstar:~/tmp/project $ cat tests/__init__.py
darkstar:~/tmp/project $ cat tests/test_startup.py
from starlette.testclient import TestClient

from app import app

def test_app():
    client = TestClient(app)
    response = client.get('/')
    assert response.status_code == 200
darkstar:~/tmp/project $ pytest -v
================================================================================= test session starts =================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.7, pytest-5.4.2, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/some_guy/tmp/project
collected 1 item

tests/test_startup.py::test_app PASSED                                                                                                                                          [100%]

================================================================================== 1 passed in 0.16s ==================================================================================
darkstar:~/tmp/project $
```

If that doesn't work, probably do as @Krishnan Shankar suggests and take a look at what is installed in the venv.

Comment: It worked! Though I had additionally to install `requests` module. So pytest was executing test files from the top level package? (from the same folder as app.py)